# Uncaught: TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I'm trying put iTunes search to my app, and I met a problem with filter method, 
I fetched iTunes api to Array, and now I wanna filter that Array by title of song. I'm not understand one thing, why console display:

```
Uncaught TypeError: songs.filter is not a function
    at findSongs (script.js:10)
    at <anonymous>:1:1<br><br>

const endpoint = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=song';
let songs = [];
fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => songs = data);
function findSongs(wordToMatch, songs){
    return songs.filter(title => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return title.trackName.match(regex)
    });
};
```

I'm struggling with this problem 2 hours and I got stuck. 
any ideas??
 thank you very much

Comment: What is the value of the "songs" parameter? What arguments do you pass to your findSongs() call?

Comment: After the assignment: `songs = data` the variable `songs` does not hold an array as you expect (probably holds an object). The function `filter` works on arrays not objects

Comment: Where are you calling `findsongs`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the classic "how to return data from an anonymous function" question...

Comment: to findSong I wondered pass songs.array, but as alfasin wrote it was object not array. Thanks a lot for a help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint returns an object which holds all songs details (as an array) in `results` property.

E.g. `{count : 2, results: [ {}, {} ]}`

---

Try  `.then(data => songs = data.results);`

```
const endpoint = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=song';
let songs = [];
fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => songs = data.results);
```